# Run directive code after ng-src

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a video player directive that uses an ng-src in its template. How do I run directive code after the ng-src has been evaluated so the video is actually loaded?

Here is the directive code:

```
return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: false,
        transclude: false,
        scope: true,

        templateUrl: "/modules/didyouknow/views/slideshow-frame.directive.client.view.html",

        link: {
            pre: function() {
                console.log('a');
            },
            post: function(scope, element, attrs) {
                /**
                 * scope.frame - frame information
                 */
                scope.frame = scope[attrs.slideshowFrame];
            }
        }
    };
```

both link functions execute before `{{expr}}` has been evaluated in the template.

The whole point of post link is it that it's executed after child post-links, in reverse order as pre links. So why isn't it executing last? It executes immediately after the prelink function so why are they even separate functions?

Comment: `link: function`, `link: {pre: function, post: function}`, all functions evaluate before child directives.

Comment: the video tag itself raises several events, can angular see those?

Answer (score 1):

You could have `$observe` inside your directive that will work same as that of the `$watch` but the difference is it evaluates `{{}}` interpolation expression.

Inside `$observe` you could see if the `ng-src` has value the only call the directive method. otherwise wait.

```
link: function(scope, element, attrs){
   attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function(newVal, oldVal){
       if(newValue){
           //call desired code when `ng-src` have value
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: The attribute is not on the directive's root element, nor does it constantly need to update.

Comment: @TahsisClaus you could deregister this `$observe` once you have value..could you add your html in your question?

Comment: @TahsisClaus you could create a separate directive that would get placed on `img` element and then this directive will have `require` attribute which would be the parent directive..after the `ng-src` URL gets populated, child directive will call the method of parent directive

Comment: Except that directive would still evaluate before the ng-src unless I put a negative priority.

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of recipes to execute the code in `link` at the moment when directive DOM 'is there'. One is using zero-delayed timeout

```
$timeout(function () {
  ...
});
```

It is is generally preferable if you're after rendered DOM or interpolated values. It is not an option here, because `templateUrl` is used and directive template is loaded asynchronously, and the template is not available during the linking phase.

Another recipe is using scope watchers/attribute observers (one-time if you don't care about data bindings).

```
var unobserveNgSrc = attrs.$observe('ngSrc', function (ngSrc, oldNgSrc) {
  if (!ngSrc) return;
  unobserveNgSrc();
  ...
})
```

> It executes immediately after the prelink function so why are they even separate functions?

This behaviour suggests what it can be used for. In parent `preLink` some things can be done that must precede child `preLink`s or the latter could benefit from, which you will rarely find useful for simple directives. And parent `postLink` executes last, and that's a good moment for 'ok, all of my children are already compiled and linked, let's do something at last'.

Comment: I do not want to do it asynchronously because it's always better to avoid it where possible in Angular. The whole point of the post link functions is to execute after child directives have been linked, at least when you use template and not templateUrl, which you mentioned, and they are NOT doing that.

Comment: You could get your money back if it only was true :) Your confusion comes from misunderstanding what linking is. From [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/compiler#an-example-of-compile-versus-link-): 'Link means setting up listeners on the DOM and setting up $watch on the Scope to keep the two in sync. '. It doesn't mean that scope bindings have already been interpolated in postLink. Because they haven't. They are interpolated right after postLink, when digest cycle hits and then settles. And that's the purpose of $timeout(...), the code will be executed right after the next digest.

Comment: For a directive that has an ng-repeat in its template, where should I put a $watch on the ng-repeat target in order to trigger the $watchFn after ng-repeat has updated?

Comment: What does it look like? Please, post a small plunker.